# passing values from different environments to ggplot aes()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got this as part of an RShiny app:

```
sizeToUse = eval(length(levels(factor(df2$Cluster))))
ggplot(df2, aes(x=Noise, y = AvgC), colour=clusterCat) + geom_point(inherit.aes = FALSE, aes_string(color=clusterCat, size=sizeToUse))
```

clusterCat is a column in the df2 dataframe, but sizeToUse is a variable declared separately and single not vector valued. Is there a way to pass both one variable that a column to the data frame and another variable that is just out there in a higher environment to aes in ggplot? I realize I could add sizeToUse as a column in df2, but this seems quite inefficient.

Comment: This isn't a reproducible example, so it's not clear why you are doing certain unusual things. Why the `inherit.aes=FALSE` argument, despite just one geom call? Why mix `aes` and `aes_string` like this? Why use `eval` in defining size to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few weird things going on there - we'd have an easier time answering if you posted a sample of `df2` (try `dput(head(df2))`).

But what you're trying to do is definitely allowed. Try this code:

```
sizeToUse <- length(unique(df2$Cluster))

ggplot(df2, aes(x = Noise, y = AvgC)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = clusterCat), size = sizeToUse)
```

A few notes:

- I made your `sizeToUse` calculation a bit more straightforward - hope this is correct
- No need to map `sizeToUse` if it's a single value

Answer (score 1):

You can try to define the variable `sizeToUse` directly in `geom_point` such as

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=Noise, y = AvgC), colour=clusterCat) + geom_point(inherit.aes = FALSE, aes_string(color=clusterCat, size=eval(length(levels(factor(Cluster))))))
```